# mac mysql after reboot

Tags: mysql, macos, startup

after reboot I try to start using mysql on my mac (10.6.5), but I get

```
can't connect to local mysql server through socket ' tmp mysql.sock' 2
```

I fix it with

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
 sudo echo
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe &
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql test
```

so my question (noob)... how to avoid having to type all that to start the mysql??
is there something I can do to start it easily?
thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system preferences app you can download and install. It has an option to "start mysql on boot".

[MySQL Preferences Pane](http://creativeeyes.at/tools/mysqlpp.php)